# DecimalFormat parse double error when number over 1234567891123456

Tags: java

I get an unexpected result when I try to parse string 12345678911234567 to double.
I use the code as below

```
    double convertedNum = 0;
convertedNum = new DecimalFormat().parse(12345678911234567).doubleValue();
```

the converted result was 1.2345678911234568E16
but I expected it was 1.2345678911234567E16, and I also try to use BigDecimal to convert as below

```
double convertedNum = 0;
BigDecimal bgNum = null;
bgNum = new BigDecimal(12345678911234567);
convertedNum = bgNum.doubleValue();
```

will get same result, I can't find what cause this.
Would someone can give me some suggests, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My best suggestion is to put the number in quote marks in the `BigDecimal` constructor - like

```
new BigDecimal("12345678911234567");
```

The constructor of `BigDecimal` with a `String` argument can deal with numbers of (just about) any reasonable size.

Not all large numbers can be stored correctly in a `double`.  It seems that the number you're trying to represent may fall in between two `double` values.  But `BigDecimal` will certainly be able to represent it correctly.

**Update**

To clarify my last paragraph, there is no `double` equal to `12345678911234567`.  There is a `double` equal to `12345678911234566`, but the next `double` is equal to `12345678911234568`.  So any attempt whatsoever to store `12345678911234567` in a `double` will result in rounding up to `12345678911234568`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I must stored by double type. So I use BigDecimal doubleValue() to parse, but the result also is 1.2345678911234568E16.

Comment: @kingaffery I hope my update clarifies why what you're asking for is impossible.